# Move file by rename()

Tags: php

I am using the `rename()` function to move files from `uploads/cart` to `uploads/order`.

Both folders have 777 permission.
Using this code is not working and there is no error shown.
`$check-image` is correctly set.

```
$check_image = glob('uploads/cart/*_'.$_SESSION['id'].'.*');
if(is_array($check_image))
    {
        foreach ($check_image as $value)
        {
            rename($value, str_replace('cart','order', $value));
        }
    }
```

Also this alternative solution did not work, no error but the file was not moved.

```
$check_image = glob('uploads/cart/*_'.$_SESSION['id'].'.*');

if(is_array($check_image))
{
    foreach ($check_image as $value)
    {
        $new_location =  str_replace('cart','order', $value);
        rename($value, $new_location);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Is `order` folder exists?

Comment: Have you had a look at your webserver's logfile to see of any error message has been reported there?

Comment: Yes it does exists.

Comment: @u_mulder ***Does the*** `order` folder ***exist?*** @ Muiter Yes it does ***exist***.

Comment: Is `/*_'.$_SESSION['id'].'.*'` file exists?  In other words are you actually finding the files you think you are finding. ( pun intended ).  If the destination exists, perhaps the source does not.

Comment: The source is there. If $_SESSION['id'] is not set the page is not reachable.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix ***Does the*** `/*_'.$_SESSION['id'].'.*'` file ***exist?*** Deliberately broken grammar is not a pun.